# ODOO Web Service sending php form to the odoo

Tags: odoo-10

i need to send request to my url using php to odoo 10 to specific model  and i got an error:  Call to a member function scalarval() on integer
please any one knows about can help me at fast time

```
<?php
include("xmlrpc.inc");

$user = "Ammar";
$password = "1235";
$db = "Test";
$serverUri = "http://localhost:8080/";

$client = new xmlrpc_client($serverUri . 'common');
$msg = new xmlrpcmsg('login');
$msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval('9_xmlrpc', "string"));
$msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval('admin', "string"));
$msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval('admin', "string"));
$res = $client->send($msg);
$val = $res->value();
$id = $val->scalarval();

$create_feedback_form = array(
        'name' =>new xmlrpcval($_POST['name'],'string'),
        'description' =>new xmlrpcval($_POST['description'],'string'),
        'phone' =>new xmlrpcval($_POST['phone'],'string'),
);

$client = new xmlrpc_client($serverUri . 'object');
$msg = new xmlrpcmsg('execute');
$msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval('9_xmlrpc', "string"));
$msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval('1', "int"));
$msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval('admin', "string"));
$msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval("feedback.form", "string"));
$msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval("create", "string"));
$msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($create_feedback_form, "struct"));
$res = $client->send($msg); 
if($res){
    echo 'Successfully Submited'; exit; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try using a more friendly and supported php xmlrpc library like ripcord, you will find a lot of more help and examples like the ones at:

[https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/webservices/odoo.html](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/webservices/odoo.html#logging-in)